# System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies foreach

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, foreach

I've tried to loop out every "category" there is in my database, and put it into the dropdown, but instead it gives me a long code starting of with this:

System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

I'm not entirely sure why? And how to fix it. At first i thought it was due to me not having the "categories" in the same model, but as i joined it in the same model, nothing really seemed to change.

So I've tried to search around the internet, but I couldn't seem to find something that resembled the problem that i had.

So I want to know, whats causing it, and what kind of solutions are available in this case scenario?

What i tried to do:
Loop out the categories from the database into the dropdown menu so that all the categories were shown, without typing them in the html _layout file.

[image: Example of the problem]

Heres my code:

```js
function dropFunction() {
    document.getElementById("inDrop").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropBtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropCon");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
@model Fisk.Models.ALL



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/css/Common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h2>Fisk.nu</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <form action="/" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="col-md-8" />
                    <input type="button" name="name" value="Søg" class="col-md-3" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul id="navMenu">
            <li><a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml">Forsiden</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="dropFunction()" class="dropBtn">Produkter</button>
                <ul id="inDrop" class="dropCon">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Kategorier)
                    {
                        <li class="dropList"><a href="">@item</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>


        @RenderBody()
        <footer>
            <p>Fisk.nu, Silovej 2, DK-8000 Århus C, Tlf. +45 87 11 12 13, info@fisk.nu</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    <script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/Slider.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/Dropdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Heres the Home Controller: 

public ActionResult Index()
{

    var ViewModel = new Fisk.Models.ALL();

    ViewModel.tekstBoks = db.front_TekstBoks.ToList();
    ViewModel.Slider = db.front_Slider.ToList();
    ViewModel.Kontakt = db.web_Kontakt.FirstOrDefault();
    ViewModel.Kategorier = db.site_Kategorier.ToList();

    List<front_Slider> sliders = new List<front_Slider>();
    List<front_TekstBoks> tekstBoks = new List<front_TekstBoks>();
    List<site_Kategorier> kategorier = new List<site_Kategorier>();

    return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access a property of the entity in your collection Kategorier -> Kategori, like @item.Name or something, Otherwise you're just printing the result of ToString()

```
<ul id="inDrop" class="dropCon">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Kategorier)
                {
                    <li class="dropList"><a href="">@item.Name</a></li>
                }
</ul>
```

Comment: oh yea... damn i totally forgot that xD 

THANKS! :D <3